# Share Properties from Child app to Base project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-8, windows-phone-8

I am Working on Windows Phone app Development: i have a requirement here.

i have 3 project,

1) BaseLibrary project - library project i.e., Phone Class Library project

2) ChildApp1 - Winodws Phone app

3) ChildApp2 - Windows Phone app

Now in my BaseLibrary i have all the .xaml  and .cs files.In my child apps i have one .cs file

Idea behind here is that both my child project UI is exactly same, so i have added all the common stuff in a library project and referenced it to my child apps.

Now, i have few changes in my child apps.

In BaseLibrary :

MainPage.xaml file;

```
namespace BaseLibrary
{
    public partial class MainPage : PhoneApplicationPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
            string appName = appSettings.getAppName();
            int appVersion = appSettings.getAppVersion();

            App_Name.Text = appName;
            App_Version.Text = "" + appVersion;
        }
    }
}
```

In AppSettingsDefaultImpl :

```
namespace BaseLibrary
{
    public class AppSettingsDefaultImpl
    {
        public virtual String getAppName()
        {
            return "XYZ";
        }

        public virtual int getAppVersion()
        {
             return 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In AppSettings

```
namespace BaseLibrary
{
    class AppSettings : AppSettingsDefaultImpl
    {
        public virtual string getAppName()
        {
            return getAppName();
        }

        public virtual int getAppVersion()
        {
            return getAppVersion();
        }
    }
}
```

In my child projects:

```
namespace ChildApp1
{
    using BaseLibrary;
    class AppSettings : AppSettingsDefaultImpl
    {
        public override string getAppName()
        {
            return "ABC";
        }

    }
}
```

Now i when i run my child project i am navigating it to MainPage.xaml in BaseLibrary project.

But in the .xaml file i have this:

```
AppSettings appSettings = new AppSettings();
                string appName = appSettings.getAppName();
                int appVersion = appSettings.getAppVersion();

                App_Name.Text = appName;
                App_Version.Text = "" + appVersion;
```

where AppSettings  is an instance of BaseLibrary, so it will get the values from the methods which are in the AppSettings of BaseLibrary,  but i want it to take the instance from child project and display the values which i have there, how can do it ?

**Output i am getting :**

1, XYZ

**Output want i want is :**

1,ABC

If the property is not defined in the child app it should take the value from BaseLibrary.

Is there any way that i can acheive this

Comment: I recommended using MEF or Unity or other containers to inject proper AppSettings class in BaseLibrary project.

Comment: @RezaArab can you please guide me , as i am new to this

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd460648%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: MEF:
In summary you must register `ChildApp1.AppSettings` as `AppSettingsDefaultImpl` type with `[Import(typeof(AppSettingsDefaultImpl))]` attribute and instead of `new AppSettings()` use `container.GetExport<AppSettingsDefaultImpl>()`

Comment: Sorry, can you please give a sample ? i am totally confused,

Comment: As you said suppose if we register ChildApp1.AppSettings then how about childApp2 again i have to make changes to base, which i dont want

Comment: You can register each AppSettings type with a key and GetExport that type with proper key you want.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45879/discussion-between-goofy-and-rezaarab)

Comment: Are the child apps creating the instance of the `MainPage` class (`var something = new MainPage()`) or is it part of the framework?

Answer (score 1):

```
namespace BaseLibrary
{
    [Export("base",typeof(AppSettingsDefaultImpl))]
    class AppSettings : AppSettingsDefaultImpl
        {
            public override string getAppName()
            {
                return "ABC";
            }

        }
}

namespace ChildApp1
{
    [Export("child",typeof(AppSettingsDefaultImpl))]
    class AppSettings : AppSettingsDefaultImpl
        {
            public override string getAppName()
            {
                return "ABC";
            }

        }
}
```

Then:

```
CompositionContainer container;// override MefBootstrapper

AppSettingsDefaultImpl appSettings = 
    container.GetExport<AppSettingsDefaultImpl>("child");
```